# How to connect to docker desktop's host to see my volumes

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-volume

I try access to my linux's docker host generated by docker desktop installation in hyper-v cause I want to see volumes that I've created with some containers. Connection by hyper-v is unreachable.

By the way, DockerNAT has a virtual switch with an internal network.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no way to access `MobyLinuxVM` in hyper-v.

For your case, e.g. you define a named volume which was in hyper-v, what you could do is just start another temporary container which use this named volume. Then, `exec` to this assistant container to check it.